# How to update Google map markers after a certain period of time

Tags: javascript, html, database, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am fetching positions from database and showing them in Google map by markers.

Currently I am updating the Google map in every 30 seconds to update/refresh the positions of the markers. Because the positions of the markers in the database are changing continuously (Basically I am updating the database continuously by an android client app).

Now I want to refresh the markers position after 30 seconds or a certain period of time, not the entire Google map.

Here is my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Demo map</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>



    window.setInterval(function(){
    /// call your function here
    initMap();
    // downloadUrl();
    }, 30000);

      var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'R'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'B'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.7561944, 90.3730818),
          zoom: 15
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;



          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file

          downloadUrl('http://demo.com/php/storelocator.php?lat=23&lng=90&radius=100', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              //-----







              var stavanger=new google.maps.LatLng(23.755421, 90.373741);
        //var london=new google.maps.LatLng(23.7561944,90.3730818);

        var london=point;


              var myTrip=[stavanger,london];




   var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
   path:myTrip,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.9,
  strokeWeight:2
  });

     flightPath.setMap(map);

              //---------------
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MAP_API&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one array and store the reference to all the markers in that array.

```
    var markerArr=[];
    markerArr.push(marker); // where you are creating new markers.
```

Remove `initmap()` outside of setInterval rather in `setInterval` iterate through the array and do whatever changes you want to do with markers.

```
    window.setInterval(function(){
    if(markerArr.length>0)
    {
    //iterate through array
    }
}, 30000);
```

Hope it helps. Happy to help:)

Answer (score 0):

Listen problem has been solved

**1.** Define initmap outside the setinterval function (this includes all functions including addmarker and all).

**2.** In set interval update markers array AND

**3.** AT THE END CALL of set interval method call `initmap()` function

Worked for me